# Create gradient legend matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to create a plot that has a legend in the bottom right corner inside the plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(23)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)
df['y'] = np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)
df['c'] = [1,2,3,4,5] * 20

# 1 is blue 5 is red
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
hexbins = ax.hexbin(df['x'], df['y'], C=df['c'], 
                 bins=20, gridsize=50, cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'))

# legend
plt.legend(handles=[mpatches.Patch(color='#A70022', label='1'),
                    mpatches.Patch(color='#303297', label='5')], 
                    loc='lower right', edgecolor='black', framealpha=1)

# colorscale
cb = fig.colorbar(hexbins, ax=ax)
cb.set_label('Color Scale')
```

[image: plot]

I can create a custom legend, but I can't figure out how to change the legend to show a cmap gradient. Or I can create a colorbar, but I can't figure out how to place it on the side of the plot and not inside the figure. Is there a way to get a gradient scale inside the legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [inset_axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html) to move the colorbar into the Axes. Not exactly a legend object but effectively the same.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
axins1 = inset_axes(ax, width='10%', height='2%', loc='lower right')

hexbins = ax.hexbin(df['x'], df['y'], C=df['c'], 
                 bins=20, gridsize=50, cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'))
cmin, cmax = hexbins.get_clim()
below = 0.25 * (cmax - cmin) + cmin
above = 0.75 * (cmax - cmin) + cmin

cbar = fig.colorbar(hexbins, cax=axins1, orientation='horizontal', ticks=[below, above])
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['25', '75'])
axins1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I am able to make custom labels for the legend with `cbar.set_ticks([1, 5]); cbar.set_ticklabels(['below', 'above'])` but is there a way that I can change the tickvalues to a percentile of the range of the colorbar? For instance if I wanted the ' below' and 'above' ticks to be in the 25th and 75th percentile of the cbar range?

Comment: I edited to add custom ticks. There is a `tick` parameter for `colorbar` and you can use `set_xticklabels` to label.

Comment: I am able to set the tick labels, it's the actual values of the ticks themselves that I'd like to find. Is there a way to see the range of numbers that the colorbar represents so I can set the ticks dynamically?

Comment: `hexbins.get_clim` returns the min and max values.

Comment: Thanks for your help! @busybear